# when to choose one between dropdown and typeahead

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, html5

I am about to design a webpage wherein I got confused between few components which suits.

Here, I would like to understand what is the best scenario for choosing between typeahead and dropdown menu as both provide a list of values.

Reference: https://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As a general practice searchable Dropdowns are used when there are a lot of Dropdown options or the Options are Categorized. It makes it easier to search and select the Option required.

Whereas simple dropdowns can be used when the options are very few like 3-5.

Another thing to consider is the Context of the user, typeahead in dropdown menus are good if the user knows what he is searching for. Otherwise its as good as a simple dropdown with a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **type-ahead** when

1. You know which option you are going to select. For example, you are likely to know product (in an e-commerce site) that you are searching.
2. Number of items are so huge that a drop-down may end up having a scroll bar.
3. You also want to show categorization such as example below

[image: Type Ahead results categorization]

Otherwise show drop-down, if

1. Number of items are small (but 4 or more)
2. Number of items are not static.

Else, if the number of items just 3 or less than it is better to show radio buttons :)